# On the hyperlink related warnings generated by the engine and the package hyperref

Tags: hyperref, warnings, multifootnote

After a few days' trying, I have essentially finished the new version of `multifootnote`. However, looking at the log file, I notice that there are some lines like these (with pdflatex):

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{...}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{...} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

or (with lualatex)

```
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name '...'
warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name '...'
```

or (with xelatex)

```
xdvipdfmx:warning: Object @... already defined.
```

Considering that the generated pdf seems fine, do I need to worry about these warnings? Since I'm not familiar with how hyperlinks work, it is not quite clear to me how to fix such issues.

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{multifootnote}
\usepackage[backref]{multifootnote}
% \usepackage[manual]{multifootnote}
% \usepackage[manual,backref]{multifootnote}
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% First approach
Lorem ipsum\footnotenumber[fn1] dolor\footnotenumber[fn2] sit amet\footnotenumber[fn3], \clearpage
consectetur\footnotenumber[fn4] adipiscing elit\footnotenumber[fn5].
\multifootnote[fn1,fn2,fn5]{This is a footnote for demonstration.}
\multifootnote[fn1,fn3,fn4]{This is another footnote for demonstration.}

\clearpage
% Second approach
Lorem ipsum\footnotetag{fntag1,fntag2} dolor\footnotetag{fntag1} sit amet\footnotetag{fntag2}, \clearpage
consectetur\footnotetag{fntag2} adipiscing elit\footnotetag{fntag1}.
\multifootnote[fntag1]{This is a footnote for demonstration.}
\multifootnote[fntag2]{This is another footnote for demonstration.}

\clearpage
SOME TEXT

\end{document}
```

Below is the current version of `multifootnote.sty`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {multifootnote}
  {2024/03/23*} {}
  {Multiple numbers for the same footnote}

\msg_new:nnn { multifootnote }
  { non-compatible-package }
  { "multifootnote" ~ is ~ not ~ compatible ~ with ~ the ~ package ~ "#1". }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/before } { multifootnote }
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded { footnotebackref }
      {
        \msg_warning:nnn { multifootnote } { non-compatible-package } { footnotebackref }
      } {}
  }

\dim_new:N \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim { 0.2ex }

\bool_new:N  \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
\bool_set_false:N  \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
\dim_new:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim

\keys_define:nn { multifootnote }
  {
    , backref       .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_backref_bool
    , backref       .initial:n  = { false }

    , left-align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left-align    .initial:n  = { false }
    , left~align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left-indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left-indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }
    , left~indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left~indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }
    , left indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }

    , manual        .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_manual_mode_bool
    , manual        .initial:n  = { false }
    , manual-mode   .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_manual_mode_bool
    , manual~mode   .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_manual_mode_bool
    , manual mode   .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_manual_mode_bool

    , unknown       .code:n     = {}
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions [ multifootnote ]

\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_backref_bool
  {
    \RequirePackage { hyperref }
  }

\RequirePackage { refcount }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n
  {
    \renewcommand { \@makefntext } [1]
      {
        \skip_horizontal:n { #1 }
        \tl_if_blank:eF { \text_expand:n { \@thefnmark } }
          {
            \@makefnmark
            \nobreakspace
          }
        ##1
      }
  }

\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
  {
    \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n { 0pt }
  }
\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
  {
    \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n { \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq
\clist_new:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_clist

% get the total page number
\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument } { multifootnote }
  {
    \label{multifootnote_last-page}
  }
\int_new:N \g_multifootnote_total_page_int
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { multifootnote }
  {
    \int_gset:Nn \g_multifootnote_total_page_int { \getpagerefnumber{multifootnote_last-page} }
  }

% First approach
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemarkmanual { O{} }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \label { multifootnote-mark-#1 }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
            } {}
          \label { multifootnote-#1 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumbermanual \multifootnotemarkmanual

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetextmanual { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
        {
          \footnotetext { #2 }
        }
        {
          \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
          \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
          \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
            {
              \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
                {
                  \bool_if:NTF \l__multifootnote_backref_bool
                    {
                      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                        { \hyperref[multifootnote-mark-##1]{ \ref*{ multifootnote-##1 } } }
                    }
                    {
                      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                        { \ref*{ multifootnote-##1 } }
                    }
                  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
                    { \Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget { \getrefbykeydefault{multifootnote-##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start} } {} } }
                }
                {
                  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                    { \ref { multifootnote-##1 } }
                }
            }
          \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } } }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }
            } {}
          \footnotetext { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {} \ignorespaces #2 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }

\seq_new:N \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnnN
  % #1 = labels
  % #2 = footnote text
  % #3 = actual page number
  % #4 = a macro to store the result
  {
    \tl_gclear:N #4
    \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        % only keep those labels that appear on the current page
        \str_if_eq:eeT { #3 } { \getpagerefnumber{multifootnote-mark-##1} }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }
          }
      }
    \clist_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_clist
      {
        \tl_gput_right:No #4 { \exp_after:wN { \l_tmpa_clist } }
        \tl_gput_right:Nn #4 { { #2 } }
      }
  }
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { multifootnote/mark }
  {
    \int_step_inline:nn { \int_eval:n { \g_multifootnote_total_page_int } }
      {
        % generate the per page mark-footnotetext sequences
        % \tl_show:n { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ #1 _seq }
        \seq_new:c { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ #1 _seq }
        \seq_new:c { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ #1 _recorded_seq }
        % leave only those labels appeared on the current page
        \seq_clear:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq
        \seq_map_inline:cn { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq }
          {
            % \tl_show:n { TEST:~##1 }
            \__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnnN ##1 { #1 } \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
            \tl_if_empty:NF \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
              {
                \seq_put_right:No \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq { \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl }
              }
          }
        \seq_gset_eq:cN { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ #1 _seq } \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq
        % \seq_show:c { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ #1 _seq }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemark { O{} }
  {
    % print the footnote mark
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \label { multifootnote-mark-#1 }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
            } {}
          \label { multifootnote-#1 }
        }
    \group_end:
    % print the corresponding footnote text
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \tl_set:Ne \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl { \getpagerefnumber{multifootnote-mark-#1} }
        % \tl_show:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
        % \seq_show:c { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl _seq }
        \seq_map_inline:cn { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl _seq }
          {
            % \tl_show:n { TEST:~ { #1 } ##1 }
            \seq_if_in:cnF { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl _recorded_seq } { ##1 }
              {
                % \tl_show:n { TEST:~ { #1 } ##1 }
                \__multifootnote_print_footnotetext:nnnnn { #1 } ##1
                  {
                    % record the current item
                    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl _recorded_seq } { ##1 }
                    % \seq_show:c { g__multifootnote_mark_internal_page_ \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl _recorded_seq }
                  } {}
                  {} {} % the two extra empty groups are added for safety
              }
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \__multifootnote_print_footnotetext:nnnnn
  % #1 = a given label
  % #2 = labels
  % #3 = footnote text
  % #4 = code when the footnote text is indeed printed
  % #5 = fallback code when the footnote text does not get printed
  {
    % \tl_show:n { TEST:~ { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
    % \clist_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { #1 } { \tl_show:n { TEST:~ {#1}~is~in~{#2}. } } { \tl_show:n { TEST:~ {#1}~is~NOT~in~{#2}. } }
    \clist_if_in:nnTF { #2 } { #1 }
      {
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
        % \clist_show:n { #2 }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
          {
            \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
              {
                \bool_if:NTF \l__multifootnote_backref_bool
                  {
                    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                      { \hyperref[multifootnote-mark-##1]{ \ref*{ multifootnote-##1 } } }
                  }
                  {
                    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                      { \ref*{ multifootnote-##1 } }
                  }
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
                  { \Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget { \getrefbykeydefault{multifootnote-##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start} } {} } }
              }
              {
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                  { \ref { multifootnote-##1 } }
              }
          }
        % \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
        \group_begin:
          \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } } }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }
            } {}
          \footnotetext { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {} \ignorespaces #3 }
        \group_end:
        #4
      }
      {
        #5
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumber \multifootnotemark

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetext { O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
      {
        \footnotetext { #2 }
      }
      {
        \iow_now:cn { @auxout }
          {
            \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@text@list { #1 } { #2 }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@text@list { m m }
  {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq { { #1 } { #2 } }
  }

% Second approach
\int_new:N \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetagmanual { m }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
      {
        \int_gdecr:N \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int
        \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
        \refstepcounter { footnote }
        \label { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } }
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
        \label { multifootnote-tag-footnote- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } }
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            % generate hypertargets for footnote marks so that they can jump correctly to the corresponding footnotes
            \clist_if_exist:cF { multifootnote-tag-hypertarget- ##1 }
              { \clist_new:c { multifootnote-tag-hypertarget- ##1 } }
            \clist_put_right:ce { multifootnote-tag-hypertarget- ##1 }
              { \exp_not:N \Hy@raisedlink { \exp_not:N \hypertarget { \exp_not:N \getrefbykeydefault{ multifootnote-tag-footnote- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int  } }{anchor}{Doc-Start} } {} } }
          }
      } {}
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        % generate list of marks in the footnote
        \bool_if:NTF \l__multifootnote_backref_bool
          {
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 }
              {
                \tl_gput_right:ce { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 } { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } \ref { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int  } } }
              }
              {
                \cs_gset:cpx { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 } { \ref { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int  } } }
              }
          }
          {
            \cs_if_exist:cTF { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 }
              {
                \tl_gput_right:ce { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 } { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } \thefootnote }
              }
              {
                \cs_gset:cpx { multifootnote-tag-list- ##1 } { \thefootnote }
              }
          }
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotetagmanual \multifootnotetagmanual

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetagtextmanual { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
        {
          \def \thefootnote { }
        }
        {
          \def \thefootnote { \use:c { multifootnote-tag-list- #1 } }
        }
      \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
        {
          \xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }
          \footnotetext { \clist_use:cn { multifootnote-tag-hypertarget- #1 } {} \ignorespaces #2 }
        }
        {
          \footnotetext { #2 }
        }
    \group_end:
  }

\prop_new:N \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_prop
% \hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { multifootnote/tag }
%   { % declare the clists to be used
%     \prop_map_inline:Nn \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_prop
%       {
%         % \clist_new:c { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _clist }
%         \int_step_inline:nn { \int_eval:n { \g_multifootnote_total_page_int } }
%           {
%             \clist_new:c { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _page_ ##1 _clist }
%             \clist_new:c { g__multifootnote_tag_page_ ##1 _recorded_clist }
%           }
%       }
%   }
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetag { m }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \int_gdecr:N \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int
    \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
    \refstepcounter { footnote }
    \label { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } }
    % add the current label number to the clist of the given tag on the current page
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \iow_now:ce { @auxout }
          {
            \@multifootnote@add@to@tag@label@list
              { ##1 }
              { \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } }
              { \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } }
          }
      }
    \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
        \label { multifootnote-tag-footnote- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } }
      } {}
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \clist_if_exist:cF { g__multifootnote_tag_page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _recorded_clist }
          {
            \clist_new:c { g__multifootnote_tag_page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _recorded_clist }
          }
        \clist_if_in:cnF { g__multifootnote_tag_page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _recorded_clist } { ##1 }
          {
            \clist_gput_right:cn { g__multifootnote_tag_page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _recorded_clist } { ##1 }
            \group_begin:
              % \clist_show:c { g__multifootnote_tag_ ##1 _page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _clist }
              \clist_if_exist:cT { g__multifootnote_tag_ ##1 _page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _clist }
                { % skip the following code on the first run
                  \clist_clear:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_clist
                  \clist_map_inline:cn { g__multifootnote_tag_ ##1 _page_ \getpagerefnumber { multifootnote-tag-mark- \int_eval:n { \g__multifootnote_tag_footnotemark_counter_int } } _clist }
                    {
                      \clist_put_right:Nn \l__multifootnote_tmp_clist
                        {
                          % \tl_show:n { ####1 }
                          \ref { multifootnote-tag-mark- ####1 }
                        }
                    }
                  % \clist_show:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_clist
                  \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l__multifootnote_tmp_clist { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } } }
                  \footnotetext { \prop_item:Nn \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_prop { ##1 } }
                }
            \group_end:
          }
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotetag \multifootnotetag
\NewDocumentCommand \@multifootnote@add@to@tag@label@list { m m m }
  % #1 = tag
  % #2 = label number
  % #3 = page number
  {
    \clist_if_exist:cF { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _page_ #3 _clist }
      {
        \clist_new:c { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _page_ #3 _clist }
      }
    \clist_gput_right:cn { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _page_ #3 _clist } { #2 }
    % \clist_show:c { g__multifootnote_tag_ #1 _page_ #3 _clist }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetagtext { O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
      {
        \footnotetext { #2 }
      }
      {
        \iow_now:cn { @auxout }
          {
            \@multifootnote@add@to@tag@text@list { #1 } { #2 }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \@multifootnote@add@to@tag@text@list { m m }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  }

% The combined interface for producing footnote text
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemanual { O{} m }
  {
    \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , }
      {
        \multifootnotetextmanual [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
      {
        \multifootnotetagtextmanual [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnote { O{} m }
  {
    \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , }
      {
        \multifootnotetext [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
      {
        \multifootnotetagtext [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
  }

\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_manual_mode_bool
  {
    \RenewCommandCopy \multifootnotemark    \multifootnotemarkmanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \multifootnotetext    \multifootnotetextmanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \multifootnotetag     \multifootnotetagmanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \multifootnotetagtext \multifootnotetagtextmanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \multifootnote        \multifootnotemanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \footnotenumber       \footnotenumbermanual
    \RenewCommandCopy \footnotetag          \footnotetagmanual
  }

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `multifootnote.sty'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to worry.

The messages mean that hyperlinks will be wrong, e.g. point to wrong target (if you have two destinations with the same name, the first is used) or go to the begin of the document (if the destination is missing Doc-Start is used as a fallback).

I can't debug all your code, but something like this is bound to give problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
[test]
\refstepcounter{footnote}\label{A}
[text text] 
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\refstepcounter{footnote}\label{B}
\end{document}
```

The log will complain about duplicated destinations and if you look into the aux-file you can see that both labels point to the same location `footnote.0`:

```
\newlabel{A}{{1}{1}{}{footnote.0}{}}
\newlabel{B}{{1}{1}{}{footnote.0}{}}
```

If you reset a counter you can't use `\refstepcounter` to reset it again, instead you have to take care of the reference and the target yourself. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
[test]
\refstepcounter{footnote}\label{A}
[text text] 
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\stepcounter{footnote}
\MakeLinkTarget[multifootnote]{}%
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{@currentlabel}{\thefootnote}\label{B}
\end{document}
```

Then you will get unique destinations and both labels will work.

```
\newlabel{A}{{1}{1}{}{footnote.0}{}}
\newlabel{B}{{1}{1}{}{multifootnote*.1}{}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Indeed I have been using `\refstepcounter` to reset the current reference type. However, I found that the duplicated destinations in my example is of the type `Hfootnote` but not `footnote`, so it seems to suggest that I am using `hyperref` commands in the wrong way. Do you have suggestion on what could be done in this case?

Comment: You probably have something like `\footnotemark\footnotetext{blub}\footnotetext{blub}` and hyperref doesn't like that at all. Sorry but the footnote code in hyperref is quite difficult and I currently don't have the time dig into it for this.